# Drupal clean url related

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7, clean-urls

In Drupal 7, I could enable Clean-URLs by clicking the checkbox in configuration and the setting saved successfully. But, however, I am **not too sure if clean urls are really working or not.**

When I open my drupal website `http://my-site/drupal/`) and click on any thing, the url appears like this:

```
http://my-site/drupal/#overlay=admin/modules

http://my-site//drupal/#overlay=admin/config
```

**I don't understand why the above links have that "#overlay="**

But, when I type in a direct clean url path into a browser like the one below, it works too:

```
http://my-site/drupal/admin/modules

http://my-site/drupal/admin/config
```

What I don't understand is that **"#overlay="** that automatically shows up in the url path when I click on any feature of my drupal site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #overlay is part of a Drupal module, it only works for the admin features. It works so that you can access the admin sections from the frontend via an overlay interface. You can disable it though if you wanted to.

Reference:
https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/overlay

Comment: Thanks joseconsador. Does that #overlay affect the functioning of clean-urls in any way?

Comment: From what I know it shouldn't, the overlay still works when you have clean url's disabled and it's functionality is only for the admin features.

Comment: cool. Thanks!! I never thought it was a different module all together. The link you posted helped alot!